# Have xvfb-run as a background process and logout

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, daemon, vps, xvfb

I'm trying to run a console server application that needs xvfb-run to run in the background. It works but when I logged out of my session the whole process stops and I can't connect to my application anymore.

I already tried using nohup, & at the end, batch and still no luck with it. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on a VPS service.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run it inside a `screen` session?

Comment: Thanks Poskvor. Apparently I'm not familiar on how to invoke screen properly with xvfb-run. Do you know how?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/454914/2249 where `yourcommand` would be `xvfb-run`

Comment: use screen as @Piskvor or try to use a tmux session

Comment: I tried the screen solution and I got a session but I can't connect even when I'm still logged in. I can see the list using screen -list but I can't connect to my application. I will try tmux next..

Comment: I have no idea how to exit when I run my app in tmux, I keep pressing "Ctrl+A, d" to detach to it once it started running but it doesn't work..

Comment: @redobot How do I exit out of tmux properly so my app is still running in the background?

Comment: Just create a new session, run whatever you need and then detach from the session (Ctrl+D). Afterwards you can attach newly and resume your work. Take a look to the following link for the basic commands: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course

Comment: This Q  may be more appropriate on the related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but my program always stops when I add a **&** background command, if I don't do this I can't use Ctrl+D to detach. Any suggestions on how to place xvfb-run in the background?

Comment: btw, my app uses UDP to listen to incoming clients. I hope this is related to my problem.

Comment: Well, I guess we need more info about your app, because I've just tried `xvfb-run xterm ./test.sh & exit` on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works.

Comment: Hi, like I said above it's a custom server application that uses UDP connections. When I try running normally it works, if I make it as a background process with & at the end, CTRL+Z to stop and bg to continue my session exits and I logged out.

Comment: @shellter ok I will try that as well, thanks!

Comment: Having a second try at screen it works in some way. The only problem now is I'm getting a timeout error when I detach my session and exit.

Comment: I got it to work now using screen and detach. Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

Run it inside a `screen` session?
                    – Piskvor

I got it to work now using screen and detach. Thanks guys! :) – scottyp